# Chrome Webdriver extension icon not visible (Version 86)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium webdriver for automation testing recently I updated to the latest version which is 86, in this version I'm unable to view the extension icon after the extension is added, but in previous versions I can see the extension icon once the extension is added, can anyone help me in viewing the extension icon in the chromedriver version 86 like the older versions.[image]

Comment: Your code trials?

Comment: Just launched chrome using the following code

```from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("google.com")```